# How to call an entity class without primary key in JPA eclipseLink?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am new to JPA eclipseLink.

I have two entity classes in header and LineItem details level. I can only call by ID in header to fetch the details from LineItem (Using OneToMany and ManyToOne). However, I have different cases where I need to call by name, customer account etc.

I have already tried with all suggestion from different forums but no luck.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Is it worth adding a code example to this? I don't know the technology, but it may make it clearer if you can show what you are working on.

Comment: Have you checked out JPA examples and demos? maybe start with https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL